# How to use a static flag in GAE Datastore?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, flags, static-variables

I would like to have a boolean flag in GAE Datastore to allow or disallow a function to run.
In my understanding, If we use a datastore property as the flag, we need to pay for each and every read operation.

It happens like this,

```
if(flag == true){
//Do 
}else{
//Don't
}
```

Could you please advise how to use a "flag" efficiently. Is it possible to use a static variable in the program itself other than saving it to the datastore?

Please advise.

Thanks,
Karthick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Memcache](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/memcache/) is your friend.  Or take a look at [Objectify](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/), which will handle caching for you.